# Interpreting percentage of crashes on Developer Console?

Tags: android, google-play

Beginner here. I just released an update on a simple app and noticed that some users are reporting crashes (see screenshot)

Is there a way to see the percentage of users affected? For example, I released the update yesterday and now see 6 to 7 crashes. My app is currently installed on 22,000 devices. I'm curious what percentage of my userbase is being affected by the update and whether it will be worth my effort to fix whatever bug is causing the crash.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l95jb.png)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely familiar with the kind of tracking the store offers, but my suggestion to you is to use Crashlytics on the Fabric platform (formerly Twitter, now Google-owned).

The Fabric dashboard will give you the info you're after, and a lot more. You'll even get stack traces of the problems and emails etc about them. You can also use it to do a more informal pre-alpha/beta test through Crashlytics and a small utility app called Beta

You can also use its Answers kit to measure key app actions that you define yourself!